# Python using multiple decorators on a method and logging the method name inside each decorator

Tags: python-decorators

Assume I have two decorator functions in a file log.py

```
def timeit(logger, level = 'DEBUG'):
    def timeit_decorator(method):
        def timeit_wrapper(*args, **kw):
            ts = time.time()
            result = method(*args, **kw)
            te = time.time()
            logger.log(logging.getLevelName(level), '%2.4f sec' % (te - ts), extra = dict(filename = method.__code__.co_filename, funcName = method.__code__.co_name))
            return result
        return timeit_wrapper
    return timeit_decorator
```

And I have a file test.py having one function which uses both the decorators like this,

```
@timeit(logger = LOGGER)
@logargs(logger = LOGGER)
def test(arg1 = 'something'):
    pass
```

When I run test.py one of the decorator prints module, func & lineno as [test.py:7 - test() ]
and other one prints like [log.py:6 - timeit_wrapper()]

How do I make both the decorator to print the actual method, module & lineno which is [test.py:7 - test() ]

Answer (score 0):

[wraps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) is specifically for this issue. It replaces select attributes on `timeit_wrapper` with those from `method` so it "looks" the same.

```
from functools import wraps

def timeit(logger, level = 'DEBUG'):
    def timeit_decorator(method):
        @wraps(method)    
        def timeit_wrapper(*args, **kw):
            ...
        return timeit_wrapper
    return timeit_decorator
```

Ensure it's done to both wrappers so that the decorator order doesn't matter.